# issues with chunksize/ data type mapping when using pandas to_sql with vertica-python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, vertica

I'm using pandas to_sql method to upload df to vertica. 
I'm using:

```
sqlalchemy-vertica-python==0.4.4
vertica-python==0.8.2
sqlalchemy==1.2.16
```

usually , I can use chunksize > 1 and it worked, but now when I run it from an editor I get

> NotImplementedError: executemany is implemented for simple INSERT statements only

when I run the same code from a jupyter notebook , I get

> ProgrammingError: (vertica_python.errors.QueryError) Severity: b'ERROR', Message: b'Type "TEXT" does not exist'

I noticed that 10 days ago , a fix was added to sqlalchemy-vertica-python, to deal with data type mapping , but If i understand correctly , those were already merged and should be in 0.4.4 that I'm using.

[link to sqlalchemy-vertica-python](https://github.com/LocusEnergy/sqlalchemy-vertica-python)

any ideas?

Comment: you could get a better and immediate help from sqlalchemy-vertica-python designers ... if you create a issues on the library itself .. they can guide you well. link:-https://github.com/LocusEnergy/sqlalchemy-vertica-python/issues